# Best Practice for Migrating Sharepoint 2010 On Prem to Sp2013 Online?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, migration

I have a SharePoint 2010 Farm with 2 major web applications with 10 diffrent Site Collection underneath it.

Majority of Sites are OOTB , but some have custom branding applied to it.

We are now interested in Migrating our Sharepoint 2010 farm to Sharepoint 2013 (Online).

What is the best migration path without utlizing Third party migration tools.

Can we migrate into using good old Database detach and attach upgrade.

What are your experiences, please share us.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, there is no luck with OOTB to migrate on-prem to SharePoint online. You can not use the database attach & detach method as MSFT dont give access to DB servers and central admin.

Only thing which really work is using the 3rd party tools. you can try them, almost everyone giving free trail. as you have less sites I would check sharegate.

you can write some code to migrate the data SPO. check this nice blog post about the options: https://en.share-gate.com/blog/migrate-to-office-365-sharepoint-supported-scenarios

Comment: "You can not use the database attach & detach method as MSFT dont give access to DB servers and central admin." So do you mean we dont have access to Central admin in Sharepoint Online?

Comment: Oh yes, we don't have central admin like what we have on Prem...in SPO we have admin center which is small subset of admin activities

Comment: Thank You Very Much Article you sent me has lots of information regarding this process. I will invest some time going through that.